# Pourquoi « si » suivi de « il » se contracte-t-il en « s'il » ?

Tags: conjonctions, contractions

La conjonction *[si](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/si)* est contractée lorsqu'elle est suivi du pronom *il* ou *ils* : *s'il*, *s'ils* et non <s>si il</s>, <s>si ils</s>. C'est à ma connaissance le seul cas de contraction d'une lettre autre qu'un `e` prononcé `/ə/`.

Comment cela s'explique-t-il ? De quand date la contraction (on ne la faisait pas en latin, pour autant que je sache ; en 1694 [le Dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k50398c/f476.image) la tenait pour acquise) ? Y a-t-il eu en français d'autres contractions aujourd'hui disparues ? Depuis quand l'écrit-on, et depuis quand la fait-on à l'oral (et accessoirement est-ce le cas dans toute la francophonie) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans le *[Dictionnaire du Moyen Français (1330-1500)](http://atilf.atilf.fr/gsouvay/scripts/dmfX.exe?LEX_ENTREE_FILTRE;BALISE=LEM;BACK;;ISIS=isis_dmf2010.txt;OUVRIR_MENU=2;s=s0a392558;)*, on trouve l'article suivant :

> SI 1, subst. masc. [TL, GD : se ; FEW XI, 561a : si]
>
> A. - Condition
>
> Par/sous tel si que. "À la condition que" : Ce fu par tel si qu'ilz
>   aroyent Grant treu de luy et, fors .X. nefz, En mer ne mectroyent
>   (CHR. PIZ., M.F., III, 1400-1403, 237). La huitante et deusiesme
>   nouvelle par monseigneur de Lannoy, d'ung bergier qui fit marchié avec
>   une bergiere qu'il monteroit sur elle afin qu'il veist plus loing, par
>   tel si qu'il ne l'embrocheroit non plus avant que le signe qu'elle
>   mesme fist de sa main sur l'instrument dudit bergier (C.N.N.,
>   c.1456-1467, 17). La cygoingne lui rendy son annel par tel si qu'il
>   deffenderoit aux porchiers et vachiers de son hostel qu' ilz ne lui
>   feissent plus de moleste (Ev. Quen., I, c.1466-1474, 116). Et de son
>   vouloir et courage M'en fit ceste obligacion, Laquelle je pris comme
>   sage, Soubt tel si et condicion Que, si la restitucion Ne me faisoit
>   devant sa mort, La vigne et la possession Me laissoit, sans luy faire
>   tort. (LA VIGNE, S.M., 1496, 519).

où l'on voit que *si* n'est pas employé seul mais sous la forme « tel si que ».

On peut donc considérer que le *i* a été élidé entre 1500 et l'édition du *Dictionnaire de l'Académie*.

Par ailleurs, il existe d'autres cas que « si » :

- *L'école* et non *la école*
- *C'était* et non *ça était*

Comment: Dans *c'était* c'est le pronom *ce* qui est élidé, le même que dans *ce sont*, ou dans *était-ce*.